# Iterate the classes defined in a module imported dynamically

Tags: python, introspection

I have a module from a child package that is imported dynamically; how can I iterate over the classes that it contains?

I have been importing the module and listing the names like this:

```
package = current_module.__name__
package = package[:package.rindex(".")] # get the package
package = "%s.sub.%s"%(package,name) # make the name of the child
print "(loading package %s)"%package
module = __import__(package) # this succeeds
for name,obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
    print name,type(obj)
```

This only prints module attributes and not the class types that the module defines:

```
__builtins__ <type 'dict'>
__doc__ <type 'NoneType'>
__file__ <type 'str'>
__name__ <type 'str'>
__package__ <type 'NoneType'>
__path__ <type 'list'>
imported_package <type 'module'>
```

---

It seems that my classes are not in the `__dict__` **unless** the `fromlist` is non-empty!  The values in the from-list don't seem to be validated though; `[""]` seems to work just fine, and suddenly the classes show up!

Can anyone explain why this is?

(Standard ubuntu python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Example: to create a dict that maps the names to the classes:

```
dict([(name, cls) for name, cls in mod.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)])
```

where mod is the loaded module

Comment: This isn't working unless the import has a fromlist-clause; question updated.

Comment: Oh and minor point i think you neant issubclass in a try block?

Comment: (First) You're right about the fromlist: I usually use `[None]` for that. Don't know why it's necessary. (Second) No, I really meant `isinstance`, not `issubclass` and without `try`. Each class is also an object of type 'type'.

Comment: `fromlist` is required to obtain what you want if and only if the module you are importing is not a top-level module (or rather, it does not contain dots). If an imported module name contains dots, the `__import__` call will return the leftmost module object if fromlist is not present, and the rightmost if fromlist is present. Compare `__import__('pkg.mod').__name__` and `__import__('pkg.mod', fromlist="").__name__`: the first is `pkg`, the second is `mod`.

Answer (score 6):

If you define `__all__` in the module you are importing, which defines which symbols will be exported, you can iterate by selecting these items specifically.

```
map(module.__dict__.get, module.__all__)
```

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1:

```py
import inspect
import mymodule

for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(mymodule):
    if inspect.isclass(obj):
        do stuff...
```

### Method 2:

```py
desired_classes = [obj for name, obj in somemodule.__dict__.items() if isinstance(obj, DesiredType)]
```

### Method 3:

Inside the module you want to iterate on:

File: `mymodule.py`

```py
class Dog:
    VOICE = 'haou'


class Cat:
    VOICE = 'meew'


class ImNotIncluded:
    VOICE = 'what a shame'


__all__ = ['Dog', 'Cat']
```

```
>>> from mymodule import *
>>> Dog.VOICE
'haou'
>>> Cat.VOICE
'meew'
>>> ImNotIncluded.VOICE
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ImNotIncluded' is not defined
```

Now to iterate you do:

```
>>> for cls in map(mymodule.__dict__.get, mymodule.__all__): cls
...
<class 'mymodule.Dog'>
<class 'mymodule.Cat'>
```